# Find the best value for KNN for statement

Tags: r, for-loop, knn, rscript

I am trying to to write a for statement to find the best value k in KNN. Unfortunately,  I tried my code snippet now several times, but it seems like it does not calculate the correct value. Do you have an idea what is wrong about the statement

```
# Tune the value of K using K-Fold Cross Validation
bestaccuracy = 0
bestaccuracy
n.folds <- 100
for (k in 1:n.folds) {
set.seed(1)
knn.cvac <- knn.cv(train= x.australian.stan, cl= y.australian, k=k)
knn.cvac.table <- table (knn.cvac, y.australian)
knn.cvac.accuracy <- sum(diag(knn.cvac.table))/sum(knn.cvac.table)
if(bestaccuracy< knn.cvac.accuracy) bestk=k
if(bestaccuracy< knn.cvac.accuracy) bestaccuracy = knn.cvac.accuracy}
print(bestk)
print(bestaccuracy)
```

Comment: Why are you checking `if(bestaccuracy< knn.cvac.accuracy)`? Don't you want it to get bigger?

Comment: @doctorlove `bestaccuracy < knn.cvac.accuracy` would show that the accuracy at the current fold is higher than the highest value seen so far

Comment: "it does not calculate the correct value" —What value(s) do you get, and how does that compare to what you expect to get?

Comment: I check if(bestaccuracy< knn.cvac.accuracy) so that if the current accuracy is higher than the bestaccuracy it shall be replaced  by the current accuracy. I checked my results manually and it does not always show the best value of k.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on a few simulation-based data and it works just fine! The only thing to notice is that you may have different Ks for which you get the highest accuracy and you print the biggest K(Because of the way it is coded).

Perhaps you can change  the line of your code to this:

```
if(bestaccuracy< knn.cvac.accuracy) bestk=c(bestk, k)
```

So you can see all the optimal Ks when you print bestk.